# How to show a classical solution of Dirichlet problem for Poisson equation is always a weak solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the Dirichlet boundary value problem for poisson equation
$$
\left\{\!\!
\begin{aligned}
&-\Delta u(x)=f(x),x\in\Omega\\
&u|_{\partial\Omega}=0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
given $f\in C(\bar\Omega)$. A classical solution is $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar \Omega)$ satisfying the above equation pointwise. A weak solution is $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$\int_\Omega \nabla u\cdot\nabla v=\int_\Omega fv\quad \text{for all } v\in H_0^1(\Omega).$$ To show a classical solution is also a weak solution, one has to show if $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar \Omega)$ is a classical solution, then $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $u$ satisfies the identity in the definition of a weak solution. I can show the identity, and I can show if $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ then $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ by trace theorem. The question is how to prove $u\in H^1(\Omega)$?

Edit: The original question was how to show $C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\bar \Omega)\subset H^1(\Omega)$, which may not be true. The above question is the one I really want to ask.

Comment: it is not true: take $\Omega = (0,1)$ and $u(x) = x \sin(1/x)$?

Comment: I don't understand your objective "To show a classical solution is also weak (I guess you mean: is also a weak solution), one has to show $C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})\subset H^1 (\Omega)$". You only have to show that the classical solution is in $H^1(\Omega)$

Comment: @Thomas Yes, you are right. Then how to show the classical solution in is $H^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: @psl2Z Your $\Delta u(x)$ is not in $C(\bar \Omega)$ as necessary for it to be a classic solution in the sense of this post

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be a classical solution to the Dirichlet problem. To prove that $u \in H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$, we proceed as follows:

Obviously $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ since $u$ is continuous on the compact set $\bar \Omega$ and hence bounded. The weak derivative is simply the ordinary derivative, what remains to show is that it is in $L^2(\Omega)$.

This follows from the fact that $\Delta u = f$ is also in $C(\bar \Omega)$ by definition of your classical solution and is hence bounded. And if both $u$ and $\Delta u$ are bounded, then so is $\nabla u$.

Now we use that $Tu = 0$ for continuous functions that vanish on the boundary, by definition of the trace operator $T$. A subtle but important theorem asserts that, for any $u \in H^1(\Omega)$, we have $Tu=0$ if and only if $u \in H^{1}_0(\Omega)$.

Finally, integration by parts shows that $\Delta u = f$ weakly.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the boundedness of $\nabla u$? All the results like this that I know of require some boundary regularity.

Comment: @Jose27 I agree we need some regularity of $\partial \Omega$ (also for the trace operator argument to work out) but I don't have a reference right now unfortunately